# Where to put logic when rendering items using a FlatList

Tags: react-native, rendering, react-native-flatlist

When using FlatList interface of React Native, where is the best place to insert logic to determine what items should be rendered/how they should be rendered?

My goal is to display some income data by date in my app with logic governing what is displayed.  The first step in the logic is to determine if the income data is undefined and, if so, to display a visual indicator to the user that there is no income data available for a particular date.

Here is the most pertinent code snippet:

```
function Item({ date, income }) {
  if (income === undefined) {
    console.log("no income data!");
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Sorry, no income data available!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{date}</Text>
        <Text>Income was {income}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here is the output on the app, to demonstrate that the basic use of FlatList is working, but some of the logic is being skipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84nHS.png)

I'll add more code for context if needed, but for the time being I'd just like to know whether putting the logic where I did makes sense, or if I'm failing to properly connect logic to FlatList in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

So , ill explain you with my code, hope that will clear it. Please find the expo snack for the same :[expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/By6X!KOAS)

So the code is

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];

function Item({ title }) {

  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
     {title != 'First Item'?<Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>:<Text>Im the first one</Text>} 
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

So basically the flat list is rendering the title in Data array. Now i wanted to make sure that if `title == 'First Item'` then ill show Im the first one rather than its title.

So ,

```
{title != 'First Item'?<Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>:<Text>Im the first one</Text>}
```

is the condition ive used. You can use your logic as you do with your JSX elements.

Hope thats clear. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Guarav-Roy.  I ended up tracking down the bug and it was not where I had first thought - which made it harder for people to help me :/ I'll post all of the code in a reply to show where I made the bonehead move

Answer (score 0):

Here's more of the code to show the bonehead move

```
function Item({ date, income }) {
  console.log(income);
  if (income === undefined) {
    console.log(income);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Sorry, no income data available!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    console.log(income);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{date}</Text>
        <Text>Income was {income}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class IncomeTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: incomeData
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.marketPlaceContainer}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Item
//bug was here in my handling and conversion of income
              income={`${item.income}`}  
              date={moment(item.date).format("L")}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.date}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class RideReportScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.rideReportContainer}>
        <ScreenHeader title={"Ride Report"} />

        <View style={styles.weatherAndEventsContainer}>
          <ScrollView>
            <WeatherTable />
          </ScrollView>

          <ScrollView>
            <EventsTable />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.incomeTable}>
          <IncomeTable />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```